# How to extract information on the two lowest elements of an r variable?

Tags: r

So my task is to "extract and display the soil types of the two lowest altitude plots using a single line of R code", and I'm not sure of the best way of doing this.

At the moment my command looks like this:

```
conservation$soil[conservation$alt < 8]
```

but that's because I know the two lowest altitude plots are below 8, so I'm kind of cheating.

Surely there's a simple way to just define the two lowest entries here instead?

Comment: You have a vector `conservation$alt`, which has the information you are seeking.  You just need to organize it.  Take a look at `unique` (to get the unique values), `sort` (to order them in ascending order), and `head` (to get just the first two values).  Then you can use `%in%` instead of `<`.

Comment: `conservation$soil[tail(order(-conservation$alt), 2)]` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the lines of `conservation$alt` with `order(conservation$alt)` in a descending fashion. Or `order(-conservation$alt)` for the lines in ascending order.

`tail(df$a, 2)` will return the last two entries of `df$a`. Alternatively, `head(df$a, 2)` will give the first two entries.

Combining these functions will give you:

```
conservation$soil[tail(order(-conservation$alt), 2)]
```

or

```
conservation$soil[head(order(conservation$alt), 2)]
```